# Obsidian Serpent drop

Tags: blade-and-soul

I've been farming for the Obsidian Serpent outfit in Yehara's Mirage, so far I've done the daily around 100 times with no success. I thought only purple items had the really sporadic drop rate, is there a difference between heroic and superior drop rates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NCSoft hasn't released actual drop rate percentages of any RNG-based item drops. So, drop-rates of blue quality items versus purple quality items is anybody's guess.

Comment: Would like to know the explanation behind the downvote, in case I am not aware of any item rarity documentation released by NCSoft.

Comment: Downvotes don't need to be explained tho, it's just users who found our posts not useful I guess.

Comment: I want to believe that there is a dynamic RND system, reacting to different conditions.